# One of the cache hosts in the cluster is down

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

## health analyzer

One of the cache hosts in the cluster is down.

I want to remove anything related to distribution cache  . the web application not working it sometimes got 403 forbidden , or 500 internal error .

Why distributed cache important ? how to apply in SP 2016 on 2 server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many cache which need a healthy DC.

- **Login Token Cache:**This cache stores the security token issued by a Secure Token Service for use by any web server in the server farm.
  Any web server that receives a request for resources can access the
  security token from the cache, authenticate the user, and provide
  access to the resources requested.
  **- Feed Cache**:This cache stores activities and conversations for use by the feeds on a user's My Site.
- **Last Modified Time Cache**:This cache stores time stamp information for all Feed Cache entities
- OneNote Throttling
- Access Cache
- **Search Query Web Part**
- **Security Trimming Cache**
- **App Token Cache**
- **View State Cache**
- **Default Cache**

Yes, you will see the access issues when DC is not stable. To fix the DC, you have to repair it.

- I would check on the server, Event log if there is any error?
- Follow this blog to repair the DC.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
- If there is only two server in the farm then stop DC on one server( where it is failing).